# How to sort a list of matrices based on fitness of each matrix

Tags: r, list, matrix, genetic-algorithm

There is a **list of** (19) **matrices**.

```
bulk.list <-list(1:19)

for(i in 1:19) {
  bulk.list[[i]]<-matrix(i, 12, 126)
}
```

I need to select the **top 10 matrices** which give biggest return when input to fitness() function.

```
fitness <- function(S)
{
  total=0
  for (t in 1:12){
    for (i in 1:126){
      total=total+(S[t,i])
    }
  }
  return(total)
}
```

I need to write these 10 matrices to another list (need not be in any specific order)

```
pop.list <-list(1:10)
```

The fitness function happens to be somewhat resource intensive, so i'm trying to use it the least number of times. So far, i have a **list of** fitness **values**

```
flist.list=lapply(bulk.list, fitness)
```

but i'm not able to comprehend how sorting this list of fitness values can result in a desired list of 10 corresponding matrices. Can i create a dataframe with these 2 lists and then sort it somehow ?
**My output needs to be the list** containing 10 matrices with highest fitness values

```
pop.list <-list(1:10)
```

PS : Being a stackoverflow noob, please pardon the initial lack of formatting

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output based on that

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it by using order() and then storing the order in another list

First the fitness was stored in flist.list

```
flist.list <-list()
for (i in 1:l){
  flist.list[[i]]= fitness(bulk[[i]])
}
```

OR

```
flist.list=lapply(bulk.list, fitness)
```

then i used order function, and stored the order in a new dataframe

```
order1=order(-as.data.frame(fit.list))
```

finally, i used that dataframe to write the top matrices into a new list as required

```
for (i in 1:10){
    poplist.list[[i]]=bulk[[order1[i]]]
}
```

not the best solution, but it works.